# How to filter data in for loop based on external vector

Tags: julia, dataframes.jl

I'm trying to create for loop based on external vector and my expectation is to create aa_loop which is prefiltered based on uni input (for test only). Why below code doesn't produce aa_loop or how to do it in a proper way?

```
names = ["Sally", "Bob", "Alice", "Hank"]
grades = [1, 5, 8.5, 4]
aaa = DataFrame(name=names, grades=grades)

#for test only
uni = "Bob"

for nm in uni
    aa_loop = subset(aaa,  :name => ByRow(==(nm)))
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating over a string produces characters, so `for nm in uni` will produce `'B'`, then `'o'` and then `'b'`. Try putting `uni` in a container, like `for nm in (uni,)` or `for nm in [uni]`

Comment: thank you! I've been reading many sites but haven't found any info about it, if you have any great resource including that topic then please share